# iOS | How to keep overlay label width same to actual image rather to imageview in XCode

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, constraints

I have an `imageview` whose view mode is set to `Aspect Fit`. I have also a label on the middle of the `imageview`. I can set label width constraints to `imageview` but it looks odd when image aspect changes on runtime.

[image: Label width is showing fine]

In this above portrait mode, at the middle of the image, the overlay text label width is same with the actual image width.

[image]

But when it's rotated, due to constraints, the ratio width becomes different and hence the width of the label.

My question is is there any way to set constraints from storyboard so that the label width will always be same with the actual image width at runtime, no matter what the imageview width becomes. Or is it necessary to handle by source code. If so, can anyone provide a short guide.

Comment: The flower name might be labeled wrong. I am a programmer :(

Comment: have you set equal width constraints for both label and imageview ?

Comment: Yes I already set it. But it needs to follow the actual image width on runtime which is not same as the imageview width...

Comment: equal constraints must be set in any*any layout ?

Comment: yes i did it. did you get my point?

Comment: if you get original image width than you just need to set width constraint according to that ... for that use width constraint not equal width ..

Answer (score 3):

To set the width to label same to actual width of a image, you need to do it programatically.

You need to set dynamic width constraint of a label and set `constant` with `image.size.width` .

It will set actual image's width to label.

Comment: Is there any way to set runtime relationship from storyboard? If not can u describe with a little bit code... Thanks for your answer. @Richard G

Comment: Instead of setting runtime relationship you can just hide/show views based on your requirements.